# How to make enums as primary key in spring data

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 enums Article, document, webcontent and theory. I want to make them as my primary in model class. currently i have written following code but how to make content_type as primary column in spring data.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content_index")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContentIndexes extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="content_type")
    private ContentType contentType;

    @Column(name="last_indexed")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar lastIndexed;

    @Column(name = "event")
    private String event;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private IndexStatus status;
}
```

I dont want to create a composite key as i will be updating same rows depending on content.

Comment: you shouldn't use enums for this. otherwise, before being able to create a new instance, you need to update your enum class.

Comment: can you suggest on this one as i want to update same row and dont want to  create a new entry.

Comment: ok. do not use enums as primary keys

Comment: Why would it be different because it's an enum? You annotate it with `@Id`, as you would do for any other type.

Comment: throw me an error "does not define an IdClass"

Comment: you should create composite key (`@IdClass`) but you cannot use enum in it.

Comment: OK. My mistake. The spec indeed prohibits from using an enum as an ID.